# Installed plex media server, and it wont start

Tags: upstart, plex

I just installed plex media server via the software center, and when I try to start it I get

```
initctl: Unknown job: plexmediaserver
```

How can I fix/debug this issue?

Comment: So I did some other stuff, and am wondering if the packages are messed up. At first I couldn't get upstart to start service and I found that the files /etc/default/plexmediaserver and /etc/init/plexmediaserver.conf were not actually installed. I did see these files in the deb file, so I copied them over manually. I had to change PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICAITON_SUPPORT to be /opt/plexmediaserver, but still plex fails to start because it is looking for stuff in /opt/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server. So is it me, or is the package not working?

Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like either the plexmediaserver package failed to install, or it has been badly packaged. This is obviously not an Upstart issue though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an upstart issue. Go into your etc/init.d/ just change back to your old plexmediaserver script by removing the upstart linked version and renaming the backedup version of your plexmediaserver script.